# openlayers - how to center map by bounding box

Tags: maps, openlayers, openstreetmap, openlayers-3, bounding-box

I'm trying to center the map by given bounding box. On [OpenLayers FAQ](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html) is even an example of it (with the swissProjection) but it just don't work. Looked around in some forums and just can't figure out how to make it work.

Maybe someone knows.

Here is the code:

```
var extent = [-9022321.0707,3022167.2243,-8849726.2608,3148441.1951];

var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:3857',
  extent: extent,
  units: 'm'
});
ol.proj.addProjection(projection);

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: projection,
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 0
  })
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct but the center is out of range from your extent. There's two ways to fix it.

First, set valid view center and level:

```
view: new ol.View({
  projection: projection,
  center: [-8936023.66575, 3085304.2097], // guess it's the center of extent
  zoom: 8 // whatever you want. 
})
```

Second, use `View.fit` instead setting `extent` on `Projection`:

```
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:3857',
  //extent: extent,
  units: 'm'
});
...
map.getView().fit(extent);
```

Comment: It was just the line map.getView().fit(extent) which solved the problem and removing the extent option from projection. I tested it out and the options zoom and center are not necessary to set because the new fit of the view is fully defined by the bounding box. Thats why i initially set it to zero. Remove or edit the upper part of the answer and I mark it as solved. Thank you!

Comment: You can choose one of them. Don't need to do first and second solution both.